# Why are the turrets in the Universal Brotherhood shooting at me?

Tags: shadowrun-returns

I want to get into the Inner Sanctum. I've got a keycard that should give me access, as well as a uniform.

[image]

They're also welcoming me when I get close.

[image]

However, as I step forward to actually go in, I'm automatically sent into combat and the turrets try to kill me.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just restarted the level, got all the same stuff, and this time they don't shoot at me. So maybe there's just a glitch.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this was a glitch that could only be fixed by restoring my game back to the point where I entered the Universal Brotherhood. I'm not sure what caused it, but I repeated all the same steps and then it worked. So if anyone else runs into this, I recommend going back to a previous save. Or just shooting the turrets.

I also had a similar issue with letting my team in the back door. I saved right before doing it, and the first time I did it, it worked. Then I ended up reloading after a bit to that save and trying again, and that time (and every time after when I'd reload) the dialog would get stuck open and basically the game would get stuck there. That one got fixed by going one save previous to that. So it sounds like maybe saved games can get into weird states on this level or something.